# Issue with Namespace on XML Parsing c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read the following XML with C#

```
 <GetAssetWarrantyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <GetAssetWarrantyResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset">
        <a:Faults />
        <a:Response>
            <a:DellAsset>
                <a:AssetParts i:nil="true" />
                <a:CountryLookupCode>XXXX</a:CountryLookupCode>
                <a:CustomerNumber>XXXXXX</a:CustomerNumber>
                <a:IsDuplicate>false</a:IsDuplicate>
                <a:ItemClassCode>XXX</a:ItemClassCode>
                <a:LocalChannel>XXXX</a:LocalChannel>
                <a:MachineDescription>XXXXXXX</a:MachineDescription>
                <a:OrderNumber>XXXXXX</a:OrderNumber>
                <a:ParentServiceTag i:nil="true" />
                <a:ServiceTag>XXXXXX</a:ServiceTag>
                <a:ShipDate>2010-04-12T19:00:00</a:ShipDate>
                <a:Warranties>
                    <a:Warranty>
                        <a:EndDate>2011-04-13T18:59:59</a:EndDate>
                        <a:EntitlementType>INITIAL</a:EntitlementType>
                        <a:ItemNumber>709-10398</a:ItemNumber>
                        <a:ServiceLevelCode>CB</a:ServiceLevelCode>
                        <a:ServiceLevelDescription>Collect and Return Initial with Dates</a:ServiceLevelDescription>
                        <a:ServiceLevelGroup>5</a:ServiceLevelGroup>
                        <a:ServiceProvider i:nil="true" />
                        <a:StartDate>2010-04-12T19:00:00</a:StartDate>
                    </a:Warranty>
                </a:Warranties>
            </a:DellAsset>
        </a:Response>
    </GetAssetWarrantyResult>
</GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
```

I think I have an issue with the namespace and whatever I've tried so far didn't work.

I've tried so far

```
XNamespace aw = "a"
XNamespace aw = "a:"
XNamespace aw = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

and some other than I can't recall at the moment

```
private void btDellWaranty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string serviceTag = tbDellServiceTag.Text;
            string uri= https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags?svctags=XXXX&apikey=XXXX";
            XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            XNamespace aw = "a";
            string result = doc.from u in Doc.Descendants(aw + "DellAsset") select (string)u.Element(aw + "MachineDescription").Value;

            XElement result = Doc.Root.Element("GetAssetWarrantyResponse");

        }
```

Any ideas?

Notes: I pass the `tbDellServiceTag.Text` correctly to the `uri` so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for a prefix (e.g. `a:DellAsset` has the prefix `a`) is denoted by the `xmlns:a="..."` of the element or the first ancestor element that contains that namespace declaration - `GetAssetWarrantyResult` in this case.

So, your namespace is:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement dellAsset = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "DellAsset").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = dellAsset.Name.Namespace;

            string customerNumber = (string)dellAsset.Element(ns + "CustomerNumber");

        }
    }
}
```